On analytic functions on the complement of a curve without jump across the curve almost everywhere
Question. Suppose $f$ is an analytic function on $\mathbb C\setminus\mathbb R$ and assume that the boundary values of $f$ from above and below the real axis (denoted $f_\pm$ respectively) exist almost everywhere on the real line, and they satisfy $f_+=f_-\in L^p(\mathbb R)$, for some $1<p<\infty$.
Is it true that $f$ extends as an entire function on the complex plane?
Background and attempts. I came across this question in trying to extend certain arguments in the theory of Riemann-Hilbert problems. I see that if $f_+,f_-$ are piecewise smooth with isolated singularities one can use Morera's theorem to show that $f$ has at most isolated singularities, whose existence is then ruled out thanks to the $L^p$ condion on $f_\pm$. However, I am not sure whether one can rule out the existence of other types of singularities in general.

This works if you have some control on $f(z)$ as $z$ approaches the boundary of your region (Hardy spaces, say), but I don't think it's true in this generality.

In what sense "the boundary values exist" ?

I would say in the following sense: for almost all real $x$, the limits $f_\pm(x) :=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0_+} f(x\pm \mathrm i ,\epsilon)$ exist.
